# Priority between service beans in a spring application implementing same interface

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I have a `@RestController` having an autowired `UserService` interface, I have two service beans `UserInMemoryService` and `UserJpaService` and they both implement `UserService` interface.

Now `UserInMemoryService` is using an in memory repository and `UserJpaService` is using a JPA repository for data manipulation. The problem is how spring makes decision which way to go? Because in controller what I have `@Autowired` is interface with no details of what concrete class to pick up.

Comment: Without seeing the code and configuration this is more or less impossible to answer. The default would be to throw an exception, if that doesn't happen you have either something in your code preventing this and preventing the 2 instances from being configured.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is how spring makes decision which way to go? because in
>   controller what I hvae @Autowired is interface with no details of what
>   concrete class to pick up.

Spring won't decide. It will just end up in an exception saying "more than one bean of type UserService found"

[Spring Couldn't autowired,there is more than one bean of `` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565186/spring-couldnt-autowired-there-is-more-than-one-bean-of-type)

You might need to use `@Qualifier` to tell Spring to use which bean

Comment: That exactly what I though would happen but the application is working :D and its picking up the UserJpaService by default!