# Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserDetailsService' type

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am using IntelliJ Idea IDE to run the code but it shows Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'UserDetailsService' type. But the same code in the Eclipse IDE is running correctly.
It is the code about Spring Security. Please Help me to fix the bug in my code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }
}

@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = repo.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("404");
        }
        return new UserPrincipals(user);
    }
}

public class UserPrincipals implements UserDetails {

    private User user;

    public UserPrincipals(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection << ? extends GrantedAuthority > getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USERS"));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository < User, Long > {
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

Why IntelliJ Idea is showing this type of error is this error in my code or something else, help me

Comment: "but it shows Could not autowire": do you mean when you try to run it? or as a warning in the IDE? Have you tried to run it in a command line?

Comment: warning in the IDE

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565186/spring-couldnt-autowired-there-is-more-than-one-bean-of-type/

Answer (score 1):

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

`UserDetailsService` has multiple implementations & beans (including `MyUserDetailsService` that you defined), therefore Spring doesn't know which one to inject in the above case.

You need to explicitly specify which bean to inject using `@Qualifier`. Like so:

```
@Qualifier("MyUserDetailsService") 
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService
```