# @Autowired says field injection not recommended

Tags: java, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

can anyone tell me why @autowired is saying field injection is not recommended and the TextWriter object 'text' also says it could not autowire because there is more than one bean of textwriter type.

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorld{

    @Autowired
    TextWriter text

    public HelloWorld(TextWriter text){
        this.text = text;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code here do not use the link for that later the link can die and the question is not useful anymore. Plus that code is so small

Comment: Yes, please put your code in the question as text not an image

Comment: Just create setter for the filed and move @Autowired on it.
Your IDE like IDEA will complains about injection, because field is package private,
so there is no classical Java way to change it.

Comment: For the second part of question see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565186/spring-couldnt-autowired-there-is-more-than-one-bean-of-type

Answer (score 11):

> can anyone tell me why @autowired is saying field injection is not
> recommended ?

For a design reason. Injecting beans directly into fields makes your dependencies "hidden" and encourage bad design :

- the class API (public/protected member) doesn't specify them while they exist.
- no way to unit test without reflection or a Spring container (the most important part for me)
- you may finish by declaring potentially many injected fields. Which may make your class with a strong coupling to other classes without that you are "really" aware of that.

Generally constructor injection should be favored (no need to annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` since Spring 4) if few fields, otherwise setters should be the way.
Both ways don't have all drawbacks mentioned above.

Comment: So you inject services called by your Spring class through the constructor ??!!

```java
public class MyClass
{
private Service1 service1;
private Service2 service2;
private Service3 service3;
private Service4 service4;
private Service5 service5;
private Service6 service6;

public MyClass(Service1 service1, Service2 service2, Service3 service3, Service4 service4, Service5 service5, Service6 service6) 
{
this.service1 = service1; this.service2 = service2; this.service3 = service3; this.service4 = service4; this.service5 = service5; this.service6 = service6; 
}
} 
```

Comment: @Marc Le Bihan Never. Please read carefully : "Generally constructor injection should be favored (no need to annotate the constructor with `@Autowired` since Spring 4) if few fields, otherwise setters should be the way."

Comment: Note: In case of using a Lombok, You can just add @AllArgsConstructor before class and all private fields will be autowired through implicit constructor.

Comment: this is rather bad reason to spam this

Answer (score 0):

I assume Spring does not see your TextWriter class as a bean. Probably TextWriter is in another package. For example, in the “models” package. If you use Spring Boot, then this will help you:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.programwithwaqas.restservice.models"})
```

I recommend you read the [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation) annotation. Pay attention to the annotation @ComponentScan.

This is in case you are not using Spring Boot

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.programwithwaqas.restservice.models"})
```

Comment: While tho OP doesn't show the actual error message, it sounds as though there are several beans implementing the TextWriter interface, rather than none.