# Spring boot MVC - Unable to Autowire Repository in the service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, model-view-controller

I have service class defined with @Autowired annotation for the corresponding repository

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class StoreService {

    @Autowired
    private StoreRepository repository;
```

The repository interface is defined as extends from JpaReepository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, String> {
}
```

And the application Autowires the Service Class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
public class StoreController {

    @Autowired
    private StoreService service;
```

Upon Running I get following error

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.mypackage.service.StoreService required a bean of type 'com.mypackage.respository.StoreRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.mypackage.respository.StoreRepository' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Med is right - you're missing the Repository annotation. and one additional thing: please don't use field-injection ! see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846048/2319333

Answer (score 2):

I think you should annotate your repository with `@Repository`, then it will be enabled automatically by Spring Framework.

```
@Repository
public interface StoreRepository extends JpaRepository<Store, String> {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `@Repository` annotation to the `StoreRepostiry` and it should work.

Here are the most used annotations that Spring recognizes and can be used for auto wiring without the need to explicitly declaring it as a bean: `@Service`, `@Repository` and `@Component`