# How to use hazel cast instance in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I want to use hazel cast in my spring boot applicaiton, but i am getting the following error
Could not autowire. There is more than one bean of 'HazelcastInstance' type.
Beans:
hazelcastInstance   (HazelcastClientConfiguration.class) hazelcastInstance   (HazelcastServerConfiguration.class)

on the following line:
@Autowired
private HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
        <artifactId>hazelcast-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Couldn't autowired,there is more than one bean of \`\` type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565186/spring-couldnt-autowired-there-is-more-than-one-bean-of-type)

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that you have two beans defined for Hazelcast object.

1. Hazelcast Client
2. Hazelcast Server

You should only have 1 bean. Probably you have both hazelcast.yaml and hazelcast-client.yml files in the classpath. You should only have one file

I will give you an example for embedded HZ server running in your project. You may want to change your pom.xml to only include hazelcast dependency. I am using

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.hazelcast</groupId>
  <artifactId>hazelcast</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Now create this file *src/main/resources/hazelcast.yaml*

```yaml
hazelcast:
  network:
    join:
      multicast:
        enabled: true
```

*spring-boot-autoconfigure* project will automatically discover the yaml file and create an embedded server for you.
Then in your code have something like this

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HzSpringTutorialApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HzSpringTutorialApplication.class);
    @Autowired
    HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HzSpringTutorialApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        IMap<Long, String> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap("data");
        for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            String value = map.get(i);
            logger.info("Map value : {} ", value);
        }
    }
}
```

In this code you are connecting to embedded HZ member.

If you need SpringBoot to connect to an existing HZ cluster, you need get delete the *hazelcast.yaml* file and create a new *hazelcast-client.yml* file for HZ client configuration

Comment: does this apply to k8s deployed apps that use hazelcast, as well?