# Could not autowire. No beans of `Repository' type found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data Jpa, this is my project structure:

```
App
  ConfigPackage
    MyConfig
  ServicePackage
    MyService
  RepositoryPackage
    MyRepository
```

Here is the `MyRepository`:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {
}
```

Here is the `MyService`:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository; <---here

    ...
}
```

Here is the `MyConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "RepositoryPackage",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "xxx",
        transactionManagerRef = "xxx"
)
public class MyConfig {
}
```

I use `@Autowired` to inject `MyRepository` to `MyService`, but IntelliJ always complains

> Could not autowire. No beans of 'MyRepository' type found

even if the code can compile and run successfully.

Why can not IntelliJ recognize this is not an error? How to remove the warning of IntelliJ?

IntelliJ Version: 2018.2.6

Comment: I see that you are using the '@Service' annotation correctly but are you using the '@Repository' annotation for your repository class? Without that annotation, you'll see an error when trying to '@Autowire'. This might be helpful as well as I don't see where your main SpringBootApplication class is located at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221645/cant-autowire-repository-annotated-interface-in-spring-boot

Comment: Problem solved by this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42025703/6690200

Answer (score 7):

> Note this is for IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.3 Ultimate Edition (But should work for other versions too)

I've noticed that this errors occurs (at least in my projects) when a configuration uses `@ComponentScan` and thus loads another class annotated with `@Configuration`. IntelliJ seems to not fully recognize it which leads to the error/warning:

1. Click in the file structure on the top folder
2. Press F4
3. Go to "Modules"
4. Select the module in which IntelliJ complains from the list
5. Click on "Spring"
6. Click on the plus icon
7. Select the configuration which provides your `xRepository`
8. Save

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it. I can not figure out why IntelliJ mistake it as an error.

Comment: No luck, it still warns...

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 does the `[alt]` + `[enter]` menu provide any solutions? You can also ignore those warnings by going to *Settings* > *Editor* > *Inspections* and turning it off

Comment: Yes, it let me add `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")`, and the warnings disappear. I do not know why...

Comment: Adding @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection") solved the problem. But when I google `SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection`, I did not find any doc or official documents...

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 I also found this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21323309/intellij-idea-shows-errors-when-using-springs-autowired-annotation, what happens when you remove the spring facet in your project configuration and let IntelliJ detect it?

Comment: The warning disappears after I removing the Spring facet. While, I'm afraid this brings another problem, even if I remove the annotations on the other classes, such as `@Service`, IntelliJ now can not detect it, so this might disable the whole detect function of IntelliJ...

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 Try to click on [Build] and then [Rebuild Project] in the top bar, this sometimes triggers intelliJ to scan everything, and as it says just completely rebuild your project

Comment: Seems there is a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/42025703/6690200

Comment: The solution I take before, use `@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")`, was suggested by IntelliJ after I enter `[alt] + [enter]`. It does work but I will not use it because I do not want to import this annotation. I will enable `spring data` plugin, like another answer said.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Intellij has trouble with your package name in `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation. Can you try putting that annotation in your main Spring class without any `basePackages` property defined?

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "xxx", transactionManagerRef = "xxx")
@SpringBootApplication
public class FooApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FooApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Your main Spring class should be in the root of course;

```
root
  ServicePackage
    MyService
  RepositoryPackage
    MyRepository
  FooApplication <---- main class here
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Use `@Repository` could elimate the warning, but `JpaRepository` is `NoRepositoryBean`. I think it should not be annotated with`@Repository`. My main class is `App`, so I suppose the repository class should be scanned.

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 can you put the `@EnableJpaRepositories` on the `App` class then? Without `basePackages` property? That would resolve I'd hope!

Comment: Seems does not help

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 How about adding the facet to your project? From `Project Structure` menu, go to your project/module and add `JPA` facet? [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GbVS2.png)

Comment: Thanks you sir, I already did that. But IntelliJ seems just can not recognize it.

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 really interesting... It might be that your intellij has trouble, did you try following the steps [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-jpa-support.html) ? Otherwise I have no other idea sadly :'(

Comment: Thanks again. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 I have one question, when you type methods in a repository, does Intellij complete them? Like when you type `findBy`, does it give suggestions?

Comment: Yes, it gives me auto complete. So I'm pretty sure IntelliJ can scan the repository. And the warning does no harm, I just don't like warnings.

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 yeah I understand, I had the exact case, no problems but annoying warnings, not sure what stopped them though...

Comment: @竹杖芒鞋轻胜马 use autowiring via constructors? That would make those warnings disappear I think, just follow [this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-injection-lombok) This is what I did I think, that removed the warnings.

Comment: Yes, I'm  autowiring via constructors... While the warning shows whether filed or constructor injection..

Answer (score 1):

Try it :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"your repository package}")
```

Comment: I already did that in `MyConfig`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue once, but 
just changing the project structure and move your MyRepository to the same package where you have the service.This should work. I don't know why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can either declare:

`@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")`

On the field, or suppress the warning through Intellij's code inspection (click the red bulb and you can suppress 'Autowiring for Bean Class' either for the field or for the whole class.

Comment: Where should I put this annotation on?

Comment: Put it above the field. It should work just as well if you put it on top of the class, but then you're going to suppress warnings for all fields.

Comment: I've tried both.. No luck... Still the warning.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")

Answer (score 0):

On your database configuration you have to declare your base packages :

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "postgreEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "postgreTransactionManager",
        basePackages = "fr.lab.test.dao"
)
public class PostGreDBConfig {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that, but still the warning...