# IntelliJ Idea + Could not autowire. No beans of type found

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I keep seeing below error in my IntelliJ Idea, however the code works fine during execution.

```
Could not autowire. No beans of 'PortfolioRequestHandler' type found. less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.
```

> Sample Code

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
public class PortfolioRequestHandlerTest {

    @Autowired
    private PortfolioRequestHandler portfolioRequestHandler;

    ...
    ...
}
```

How do I get rid of this? I am using IntelliJ Idea ULTIMATE 2018.2

Comment: Make sure Spring Context is configured for the module: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-support.html#configure-spring-project-facet Try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download If you continue to see the error but application works as expected, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with a sample project.

Answer (score 8):

Are you sure that your Spring beans are wired correctly and that it's an IDE problem?

1. check if your `PortfolioRequestHandler` class is annotated with `@Service`, `@Component` or `@Repository` (bean config via component scanning)
2. otherwise check if your bean is wired in a `@Configuration` annotated class -> in that case there should be a method that returns an instance of type `PortfolioRequestHandler` and that's annotated with `@Bean`
3. try adding a configuration class (as mentioned in 2.) and add this class to your `@SpringBootTest(classes = {...}` annotation; see example below

```
@Configuration
public class CustomBeanConfig {

   @Bean
   public PortfolioRequestHandler get PortfolioRequestHandler() {
       return new PortfolioRequestHandler();
   }
}
```

`@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class, CustomBeanConfig.class})`

5. have a look at this one, maybe helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50267869/150623

Comment: The #3 solved my issue.

Comment: solution no 3 solved my issue, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If by any chance `PortfolioRequestHandler` is declared in a different module, you can let Spring to scan and find your Bean(s) specifying the package path.
i.e.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "PATH TO THE MODULE WHERE YOUR BEAN IS DECLARED") {

}
```